# Instead of Glances, I installed openstack-glance by mistake

Tags: linux, debian, openstack, openstack-glance

First of all, I know nothing about openstack, keystone, glance ... But,

I made a mistake when I install [Glances](http://glances.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in my Debian server.

I tried to install glances following [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-install-glances-monitoring-tool/)

I have done this :

```
sudo apt-get install glances
```

In fact, Instead of glances, it suggested to me to install openstack - glance. I haven't seen clearly the question and I have choosen (Y) to continue and have committed this error.

Now, I get blue screen which is the configuration of keystone and glance-api.

I am wondering whether my server will be reboot after the configuration of keystone / glance-api ? I don't want to reboot my server.

whether keystone or glance impact network config ?

I am waiting in front of my blue screen for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I get blue screen which is the configuration of keystone and glance-api.

Just abort it.  The Keystone / Glance services cannot start until the configuration procedure has completed.

The you should be able to uninstall that package that was installed by mistake.

> I am wondering whether my server will be reboot after the configuration of keystone / glance-api ?

It won't do that.  Not even updating the kernel on a Linux system will force a reboot.  But it may attempt to start the Keystone and Glance services, which you don't want to happen.  (It would be harmless to do that, but you don't want your system running services that you don't need and don't understand.)

> Do you know whether 'openstack-glance' will stop some process running or close some ports reserved by others services ?

There is no plausible reason for a package to close ports reserved for other services or kill processes belonging to other services.

---

However ....

> I don't want to reboot my server.

This is not a healthy situation.  If your server is running something so critical that you should not reboot it, then your should NOT be installing packages on it in an uncontrolled fashion, like you seem to be doing.  (IMO)

Comment: Thank you, How to abort blue screen (configuration) ? Ctrl+C ?

Comment: If necessary, open a new shell, use `ps -aux | less` to identify the process and then `kill` it.

Comment: I found the process "apt-get install glances" lanched by root, i killed it. I return to my black screen in my first shell, How to do cleaning ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove <package>` where `<package>` is the package you want to uninstall.

Comment: I got `dpkg was interrupted...`, I have done `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get update` to fix that. and then I removed packages by `sudo apt-get remove --purge glances`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Gut feeling: no installation process will force a reboot on you. Maybe you are told that you should reboot, but it will not happen automatically.

I would just do whatever is necessary to complete the installation. And when it is finished, check out the installed packages; and apt-get purge all of them.

If you are afraid of rebooting your server; and want to be sure:

then quickly install a VirtualMachine with a matching Debian level; and repeat your steps; until you are in front of the same screen - and see what happens afterwards. But as said - I am pretty sure that completing the installation will **not** trigger a reboot.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Do you know whether 'openstack-glance' will stop some process running or close some ports reseved by others services ?

Comment: I do not know; but that would surprise me, too.